# ReactJS - Griddle not using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript, griddle

I'm using Brunch and CoffeeScript to glue my files together. I added Griddle to vendor.js. Griddle is now accessible and it's a function. So I can call `Griddle` and it's defined.

But how can I use it with ReactJS ?

I tried to use it like I would do for my one components:

```
Griddle = React.createFactory(Griddle)
    ...
    render: ->
      Griddle {results: fakeData}
```

This will return:

```
Warning: getDefaultProps is only used on classic React.createClass definitions. Use a static property named `defaultProps` instead.
react-with-addons.js:21628 Warning: getInitialState was defined on Griddle, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?
react-with-addons.js:7400 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

Basically, I want to use an external module to render tables without JSX.

Comment: Of course I'm overwriting `Griddle`, it was just for the purpose of the example.